# Abort sequential VS workflow in parallel activity

Tags: workflow, sequential

let's say I have a list workflow that has two parallel activities. The first one is for executing the actual workflow. The second parallel activity is for "listening" for when any task created in the first parallel activity has changed. This picture explains better what I want to do:

[image]

As you can see, I have multiple tasks in my first sequence. In my second sequence, I need to "listen" for when a user sets the "State" field in either of these tasks to "Deferred" and abort the workflow afterwards.

So is this possible? If yes, what is the best way of doing this? I am very new to workflows and I know how to setup tasks, loops and if/else blocks, but I can't seem to figure out how I would implement something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that parallel activity is similar to the one that is in Sharepoint Designer, but if it is both need to complete before they move to the next step.

You might be better off just doing an if else block after each on tasked changed and if it is deferred end the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for you solution man, this led me to something else which works a little better for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

OK I didn't find any way to do it like I specifically stated above, but I got something similar working.

In my second parallel activity, I have 3 activities:

```
CreateTask -> Creates a task for "aborting" the workflow
OnTaskChanged -> For listening when the aborting task has been completed
TerminateWorkflow -> For throwing an error and thus terminating the workflow
```

Basically, I just setup the CreateTask and OnTaskChanged activities and below the OnTaskChanged, I have a IfElse Block that determines whether the abort task has been completed. This is where my TerminateActivity comes into play. I put this activity into the 'True' Path of the if..else block so it will only terminate the workflow when the state of the abort task has been set to Completed. If not, it will just enter the else branch and exit the workflow gracefully.